# Spring reactive Unsupported extension type: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEvaluationContextExtension

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I recently upgrade to Spring Boot 2.5.2,and now I get the following stacktrace; but I found no clue to solve the problem, even using another, nothing to do I still have the same error with (`doOnNext() + subscribe()` instead of `block()` )

Anyone have an idea plz?

Here my code:

```
Flux<WorkOrderHistory> workOrderHistoryFlux = workOrderHistoryRepository.findByDiCode(diCode);
List<WorkOrderHistory> workOrderHistoryList = workOrderHistoryFlux.
doOnError(throwable ->  {
    throwable.printStackTrace(System.err);
}).collectList().block();
```

Below my repository:

```
public interface WorkOrderHistoryRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<WorkOrderHistory, String> {

  Flux<WorkOrderHistory> findByWorkOrderId(String workOrderId);

  @Query("SELECT * FROM workorder_history WHERE di_code = ?0 ALLOW FILTERING")
  Flux<WorkOrderHistory> findByDiCode(String diCode);
}
```

And the stackstrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported extension type: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEvaluationContextExtension@7bca7b6c

at org.springframework.data.spel.ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.lambda$getExtensions$4(ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:149)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:374)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:218)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFromMonoOperator.subscribe(FluxFromMonoOperator.java:83)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54)
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8235)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen.subscribe(FluxUsingWhen.java:93)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1702)
at fr.dalkia.workordercomputer.webinage.business.WorkOrderManager.processByDiCodes(WorkOrderManager.java:171)
at fr.dalkia.workordercomputer.webinage.business.WorkOrderManagerIRTaskTest.processByDiCodesTestCase4C(WorkOrderManagerIRTaskTest.java:165)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:54)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1703)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: Are you using JPA?

Comment: @Toerktumlare  yes of course, on the WorkOrderHistory (is an entity), why ? isn't possible to use JPA with reactive from the 2.5.2 ?

Comment: Webflux does not have support for JPA afaik since hibernate has not implemented support for the reactive databasedriver R2DBC but that might have changed. What version did you upgrade from? And has it worked for you before